# Как написать программу подсчета циклов?

Tags: c циклы

Как на С написать программу, которая посчитает `(1+1/1^2) * (1+1/2^2) * ... * (1+1/N^2)`?

Comment: @ffbarney, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int N = 5; // Ваше N
  int i; // Counter
  double Final = 1; // Искомое число. Почему 1? Потому что будем умножать. Умножим на 0 - будет ноль.
  for ( i = 0; i < N; i++ )
      {
          double PowValue = pow ( i + 1, 2 );
          double Value = ( 2 / PowValue ); // Саму исходную формулу можно чуть-чуть поменять
          Final *= Value;
      }
  printf ("%f\n\r", Final );    
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-нибудь типа такого:

```
double calculation(int rounds) {
    if (rounds <= 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    double temp = 1;
    while (rounds > 0) {
        temp = temp * (1 + 1 / (rounds * rounds));
        rounds--;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

И не кричите меня, я не помню, как правильно осуществлять декремент в while, где валяется функция степени, и есть ли `*=` в С.

Comment: Это хорошо, что в отличии от @niks123123, Вы забыли о функции `pow()`.

Правда, на всякий случай, я бы привел один из сомножителей в знаменателе к `(long long)` (поскольку при int N уже при N = 65536 наступит переполнение).

Comment: @avp, если честно, я вообще не задумывался о переполнении, когда писал.

Comment: Это не страшно. Теперь будете вспоминать. Т.е. правильно написать

    temp *= 2.0 / ((long long)rownds * rownds);

Операция `*=`, естественно, в Си есть. IMHO во все остальные языки эти операции (+=, \*= ...) пришли из Си.

--

А вот `2 / (целое)` -- это неправильно. При целочисленном делении все члены, кроме round == 1 окажутся равными 0 (!).

Answer (score 0):

А про рекурсию забыли?

```
double calculate(int extent)
{
    if (extent<2) { // проверка на степень == 1 - выход из рекурсии
        return 2;   
    }
    return (1+1/(double)(extent*extent))*calculate(extent-1);
}
```

Вызов:

```
double result = calculate(5);
```